# Creating a file in client machine

Tags: php

Is there any possbile solutions in PHP to create a file or directory on the client machine. 
**Note:**
Downloading the file is not a solution to me. only once the user access the website and execute some function and it allows to create a files or directory on the client machine.

Comment: only file you are allowed to create on client machine is a cookie :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply, you can't do that in php or any other server side language.

Reason is simple server side application and scripts have access only to local resources where they are launched. So when you run your application on local computer, everything works as you wish for. But because of how HTTP works and because of safety reasons you cannot access user local files.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible , except- Flash, Applet ( Not sure ), Microsoft Silverlight ! and for those you will also have to give permission. But i don't think it is a good idea to store file on client machine, try another :)

Comment: no not for storing a file we actualy want to execute some command from the client machine using the web application we created.

Comment: creating a file or a folder on a client machine would be a step forward for us.

Comment: Then why not this :-   terminal.php?cmd=<cmd>   ? O.o

Comment: Sometimes is good ... example for POS application . You generate the fiscal receipt to cash register. Cash register need a  text file to execute the fiscal receipt. So I need this to be done on client side where cash register is installed.